# Would South Korean games be on topic?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions

We already allow question on Japanese games so long as it's plot related. on the weekend as i was showing off to my brother my backlog of games i remembered that *Magna Carta: The Phantom of Avalanche* which was a South Korean game was never translated, a patch was being worked on but it's been abandoned.

*Magna Carta: Crimson Stigmata* and *Magna Carta 2* were localized officially so there is a gap in the series. i already know we allow questions on Manhwa but i am wondering would we allow questions on Korean games aswell?

Answer (score 3):

I would image that this would be okay.

If we allow Japanese game plot questions, and allow Korean manhwa. Then a (semi)combination of the two is probably fine.